# 'Unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, selector

I am receiving the following Error

```
[UIViewController setThisViewData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71800b0
2012-10-24 16:06:05.071 Movie Rental[5468:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setThisViewData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71800b0'
```

at the following lines of "**basicInfoViewController.m**":

```
 contactInfoViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
 destViewController.thisViewData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.viewData];
```

My **contactInfoViewController.h** looks like

```
@interface contactInfoViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableDictionary *thisViewData;
}
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *thisViewData;
```

and i have included the

```
@synthesize thisViewData;
```

for the implementation.
Why am I getting this error ?

Comment: What you are getting back from `segue.destinationViewController` clearly isn't an instance of `contactInfoViewController`, but `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you haven't set the class for the UIViewController in interface builder so instead of getting a contactInfoViewController you are getting a UIViewController.