# Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c

Actually, the problem is in 
`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray* arrayOfObjects;`

should be: 
`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* arrayOfObjects;`
 yeah? Thank,s for that guys!

I do not exactly understand how this bug worked, but I will try to get to know :)

---

I have trying to solve one problem since over an hour... I am afraid it is something very simple, but something I do not understand yet. I am guessing that this is something with memory management stuff cause this is my definitely weak point yet.

Post a little bit similar to
['Unrecognized selector sent to instance'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047705/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)
and some others but they didnt solved my problem...

In a nutshell (pasting much cause don't know where the potential bug is):

```
@interface MyCustomObject : NSObject {
    NSString* name;
    int birthDate;
    double heightInMeters;
}

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString * name;
@property(nonatomic) int birthDay;
@property(nonatomic) double heightInMeters;

-(id)initWithDate:(int)birthDate 
        AndName:(NSString *)nameString 
        AndHeight:(double)h;
@end
```

//////////////////////////////////

```
#import "MyCustomObject.h"

@implementation MyCustomObject

@synthesize name;
@synthesize birthDay;
@synthesize heightInMeters;

-(id)initWithDate:(int)bd AndName:(NSString *)nameString AndHeight:(double)h{

    if(self = [super init]){
        self.birthDay = bd;
        self.name = nameString;
        self.heightInMeters = h;
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
@end
```

And some kind of database for `MyCustomObject`s:

DataCollection.h:

```
@interface DataCollection : NSObject{

    NSMutableArray* arrayOfObjects;

}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray* arrayOfObjects;

    -(void)addElement:(id)el;
@end
```

And implementation:

```
    #import "DataCollection.h"

    @implementation DataCollection 
    @synthesize arrayOfObjects;

    -(id)init{
        if(self = [super init]){
            self.arrayOfObjects = [[NSMutableArray array] init];
            NSLog(@"Number of record before init: %d", [self.arrayOfObjects count]);
            [self addElement:[[MyCustomObject alloc] initWithDate:1988 AndName:@"Georg" AndHeight:1.88]];
            [self addElement:[[MyCustomObject alloc] initWithDate:1951 AndName:@"Sebastian" AndHeight:1.58]];
            NSLog(@"Number of record before init: %d", [self.arrayOfObjects count]);
            return self;
        }
        return nil;
    }

    -(void)addElement:(id)el{
        // UNRECOGNIZED SELECTOR ????
[self.arrayOfObjects addObject:el];
    }

    @end
```

Result is:

> 2013-03-05 15:42:56.826 XMLTest[11787:207] Number of record before
>   init: 0 Current language:  auto; currently objective-c 2013-03-05
>   15:43:51.446 XMLTest[11787:207] -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x6816110

Do you see what I am doing wrong? I am guessing that this is something with memory management stuff

Comment: Why are you using (nonatomic, copy) and not (nonatomic, strong) ?

Comment: Or at the very least `(nonatomic, retain)`

Comment: That could likely be your problem, when you do the assignment of `self.arrayOfObjects = blah` it is calling `copy` on the `NSMutableArray` which may be returning a non-mutable copy of the array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray* arrayOfObjects;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* arrayOfObjects;
```

That should fix your problem

Comment: You should mention that `copy` will create an immutable copy (hence the error the OP is seeing), as well as not actually updating the instance variable as desired.

Comment: Yes, as trojanfoe said, when your @property directive is set to copy, your getter method will actually make a copy of your arrayOfObjects, but it will be an NSArray instead of an NSMutableArray. NSArray does not implement the addObject: method, therefore resulting in the Unrecognised selector error.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually read your question - it's too long, but I think I may know your problem. Looking only at the debugger output at the end of your post, it looks like you're trying to send `addObject:` to an `NSArray` object. If you want to add and remove objects to an array, you need to use `NSMutableArray` instead.

Comment: Yeah, a sneaky problem for sure. :) The point is - trust the debugger messages, follow them up. This would lead you to "why is my mutable array being converted to an array?" which would lead to your answer. :)

Comment: Yeah, after some research and learning I found your answer not so bad :D