# Unrecognized selector sent to instance Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, bitwise-operators

I am receiving error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString
>   subjectType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I am trying to sort students in my app to arrays by the subject type that they are learning.

```
AMStudent* student = [[AMStudent alloc] init];

NSMutableArray* studentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray* studentNameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Student1",  @"Student2", @"Student3", @"Student4", @"Student5", @"Student6", @"Student7", @"Student8", @"Student9", @"Student10", nil];

[studentArray addObjectsFromArray:studentNameArray];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [studentNameArray count]; i++) {

    student.name = [studentNameArray objectAtIndex: i];
    [student randomAnswer];
    NSLog(@"%@", student.description);

}

NSMutableArray* techArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* humArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (AMStudent* stud in studentArray){

    if ((stud.subjectType & AMStudentSubjectTypeDevelopment) | (stud.subjectType & AMStudentSubjectTypeMath)) {
        [techArray addObject:stud];
    } else {
        [humArray addObject:stud];
    }
}
```

I cant figure out what exactly I am doing wrong, because it crashes in this stage:

```
if ((stud.subjectType & AMStudentSubjectTypeDevelopment) | (stud.subjectType & AMStudentSubjectTypeMath)) {
        [techArray addObject:stud];
    } else {
        [humArray addObject:stud];
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception message?  It will tell you what the class was and what the selector that was sent is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Unrecognized selector sent to instance'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047705/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: Add detailed crash log.

Comment: if the object is nil, you will be getting this crash. Are you are the object is not nil

Comment: @gurmandeep you can send any selector to `nil` in objective c and it won't crash; it just returns nil.

Comment: My bad, was referring null. @Paulw11

Comment: Exception message was: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString subjectType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fill `studentArray` using:

```
[studentArray addObjectsFromArray:studentNameArray];
```

So `studentArray` contains `NSString` instances. You then attempt to process the array using:

```
for (AMStudent* stud in studentArray){
```

This does **not** magically convert the `NSString` instances in `studentArray` into `AMStudent` instances. You don't get an error at this point as `studentArray` can contain objects of any type so the compiler just trusts you know what you are doing and places a reference to an `NSString` into `stud`. You then do:

```
   if ((stud.subjectType ...
```

and this requires `stud` to reference an `AMStudent` object, which it does not, it references a (constant) string and so you get the error:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[**__NSCFConstantString** subjectType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Instead of copying the names of the students into `studentArray` you need to create instances of `AMStudent` and add those to the array. Did you intend to do that in the first loop maybe?

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot for Your wide answer, I understood my mistake:

Answer (score 4):

You are calling

```
stud.subjectType
```

in the studentArray after copying the studentNames (NSString) to the student array:

```
[studentArray addObjectsFromArray:studentNameArray];
```

NSString won't recognize subjectType.

Answer (score 0):

techArray and humArray (NSArray) type change not working add object function.

```
NSMutableArray *newtechArray = [techArray mutableCopy];


NSMutableArray *newhumArray = [humarray mutableCopy];

if ((stud.subjectType & AMStudentSubjectTypeDevelopment) | (stud.subjectType & AMStudentSubjectTypeMath)) {
        [newtechArray addObject:stud];
    } else {
        [newhumArray addObject:stud];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for Your wide answer, I understood my mistake. Just added one more loop and added object student.

```
for (NSInteger numberOfStudents = 0; numberOfStudents < 10; numberOfStudents ++){

    AMStudent* student = [[AMStudent alloc] init];
    student.name = [studentNameArray objectAtIndex:numberOfStudents];

}

[studentArray addObject:student];
```